# UID of a deleted account

Tags: linux, users, forensics

How can an administrator find the UID of a user that's been deleted with the `userdel` command?

Comment: Is the account already deleted?

Comment: @ Michael Mrozek yes.

Comment: Is the home directory still around?  An "ls -l" of that directory should show the UID, given that the entry from /etc/passwd is gone.

Comment: @cjc no! Home directory is deleted and the admin doesn't now which file belongs to that account.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By looking at `/etc/passwd` in the backups taken of your system from the day/week/period before the user deletion.

If `userdel` was used with -r, then both the home directory and user's mail spool have gone.  If it wasn't used with -r, check for the user's mail spool, or perhaps a crontab if you're very lucky.

If there are no backups, and no obvious files owned by that user you can check, then you'll need to scout around places like `/tmp` and look for files with UID's as owners and try and work it out - but really, your backup is your best bet.

Edit: as jw013 points out you could also use `find / -nouser` to find files which have no matching user for the file's UID.

Comment: You can try: `find / -uid <UID>` to find *all* files owned by the user.
`-uid` is an option on GNU find at least.

Comment: But that assumes you know the UID you're looking for - the question is how to find the UID of a user that's no longer present.

Comment: Actually, GNU `find` has the [`-nouser`](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Owner.html#Owner) test for this purpose - it tests true for files whose uid does not correspond to any user on the system.

Comment: @EightBitTony: D'oh.

Comment: @jw013 this approach works only if you have deleted *only* one user from system but if you have a system with 300 users that worked for 5 years with tens of deleted users you can't use this method at all.

Comment: @XinHua If you have tens of deleted users with files still lying around you should probably do some clean-up anyways.

Comment: This is an example that only describes a situation in which your suggestion doesn't work nothing more.

Comment: Well, -nouser in combination with -mtime would let you find out the most recently active unowned files, which would probably help.

Answer (score 1):

If there are 10 users and 1 deleted user, you could check /etc/passwd for which UID from 1000 and up is missing.

Comment: Not 100% reliable, particularly if more than one account has been deleted, but likely to be quick if it works.